# Spring Data JPA aggregation group by period of time

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

at the moment I develop a small eCommerce App with Spring Boot and AngularJS. For my data-access layer I use Spring Data JPA with a MySQL-DB. My next step is, that I want to plot some statistics for specific products. For example: how did the review-ratings from a specific product develop over time. So I would like to specify a period of time (e.g. 01.2016 - 03.2016) and than formulate one query that returns 10 or 15 Points in time (within the range) with the average rating of the reviews in this period. So that i can plot a Chart from that.

I found ways with Spring Data to get the average for one period (Between x and y), but then I would have to make 10 queries to the database (for each dot). So I want to know, if it is possible to formulate a query with spring data that splits a time-period in a fixed number of sub-periods and gets the average of customer-ratings within each sub-period? If yes, how can I achieve that?

An excerpt of my Data Model Looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_placement")
public class ProductPlacement implements Serializable{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "product_placement_id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "title")
   private String title;

       ...

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="productPlacements")
   private Set<CustomerReview> customerReviews;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_review")
public class CustomerReview implements Serializable{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "customer_review_id")
   private String reviewIdentifier;

    ...

   @Column(name = "rating")
   private Integer rating;

   @Column(name = "dateOfCreation", nullable=true, unique=false)
   private LocalDateTime dateOfCreation;

   @JsonBackReference
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(
        name = "review_to_product",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_review_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_placement_id")
        )
   private Set<ProductPlacement> productPlacements;
}
```

Thank you!